# Set a post to 'pending' if it get more then 3 reports in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using wp user frontend, and I have also downloaded a plugin called 'WP-Reportpost'.

What I am trying to do is that I want users to add post with WP User Frontend (which is working), but when a post get more then 3 reports from other users it should change it status from 'Published' too 'Pending'.

I am trying to make a function in functions.php, but I can't get the code to work.
So far I got this:

```
 /* Set posts to pending */
function change_post_status($post_id,$status){
    $current_post = get_post( $post_id, 'ARRAY_A' );
    $current_post['post_status'] = $status;
    wp_update_post($current_post);
}
```

and in reports.php I have put this code:

```
if(count($report) >= 3){
    change_post_status($report->postID,'pending');
}
```

The the post still has status as 'Published' and not 'Pending'.

Any tips?

Comment: How do you retrieve the $report object in reports.php? Check the output of $report and see if it outputs null, that could be one possibility to exclude.

Comment: The $report didn't print out any value other than 0 or 1. So I had to run an foreach loop. So now I am able to at least get how many reports one post has. But I still havn't figured out a way to set it to pending when it gets 3 reports.

Comment: So, just to make sure the output of count($report) returns 3 or greater and this is still not working?

Comment: Well, I changed from count($report) to $i, and then used $i inside a foreach loop to collect how many times it runs, I get the correct number. As if a post got 2 reports it prints out 2 and so on. I did a test on the page to show a button if( $i >= 3 ) and it worked. But I can't get it to change the posts status to 'pending'.

Comment: But you're still using $report->postID to output the post_id when you call your change_post_status function; So by using the count you incremented in your loop you only solved half a problem really ...my point is if $report itself is a null object, then you will still be attempting to call a non existing property (postID) on a null object...are you even sure it's not $report->ID or $report->post_id? my suggestion is to turn on debugging and actually output the $report object to a log file prior to calling that if(count(...conditional, or show the part of the code where $report is set.

Comment: Here's a few useful links to get you started with debugging in WordPress environment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress and http://fuelyourcoding.com/simple-debugging-with-wordpress/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help with the code. I at least find the way to figur this out.

I placed this code inside the functions.php file

```
/* Code to change post status */
function change_post_status($post_id,$status){
    $current_post = get_post( $post_id, 'ARRAY_A' );
    $current_post['post_status'] = $status;
    wp_update_post($current_post);
}
```

to use the function I did this:

```
change_post_status($report->postID,'pending');
```

What I did was to use print_r to get what the $report object was saving and get the postID from there.

Thanks for the help guys!